# How to change select2 multiselect control's delimiter to semi-colon?

Tags: jquery, multi-select, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use Select2 jQuery library on MultiSelect control. The controls works fine, but I need to change the default delimiter (separator) of values that select2 uses for Multiselect controls.

Currently output of retrieving the value from multiselect control's value is `comma`, and I need it to be `semi-colon` separated values instead, how can this be done?

```js
$("#btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $("#result").text('Output: ' + $("#example1").select2("val"));
});

$("#example1").select2({
  seperator: ";"
});
```

```css
#btn {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
#result {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.js"></script>

<select id="example1" placeholder="Select ..." class="" style="width:100%;" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="Option 6">Option 6</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" />
<div id="result">Output:
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned your option values may contain commas, my original Answer will not work.  Try this instead (I've added commas to your option values for demo purposes):

```
$("#result").text('Output: ' + $("#example1").select2("val").join(';'));
```

```js
$("#btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#result").text('Output: ' + $("#example1").select2("val").join(';'));
});

$("#example1").select2();
```

```css
#btn {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
#result {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.js"></script>

<select id="example1" placeholder="Select ..." class="" style="width:100%;" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Option, 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option, 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option, 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option, 4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="Option, 5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="Option, 6">Option 6</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" />
<div id="result">Output:
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is why i m looking for replacing `comma` as it is part of values in database.

Comment: OK. I noticed that in your example you spelled "separator" incorrectly, but even with that fixed, your example still is not working as expected, and at the moment I'm not sure why. I'll let you know if I see anything else.

Comment: It seems there's actually no need to split `$("#example1").select2("val")` first, so I've modified my answer accordingly. Please give it a try. I also added commas to your option values for demo purposes, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This also works for me..

```
.select2-selection__choice {
    &:not(:nth-last-child(-n + 2)):after {
        content: ',';
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).